# Accessing cookies from ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I'm working my way through Chapter 9 of https://www.railstutorial.org/ and am running into trouble with an integration test.

The test looks like this:

```
class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  ...
  test "login with remembering" do
    log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '1')
    assert_not_empty cookies['remember_token']
  end
  ...
end
```

The call to log_in_as is a function added to ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest in my test_helper, and appears to be working as expected.  One of the side effects of this function is that a cookie named 'remember_token' gets set.  However, the assertion fails with the message:

```
FAIL["test_login_with_remembering", UsersLoginTest, 14.115229932998773]
test_login_with_remembering#UsersLoginTest (14.12s)
    Expected nil (NilClass) to respond to #empty?.
    test/integration/users_login_test.rb:48:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
```

Any idea what's going on here?  Running the test in the debugger seems to suggest that the cookies object doesn't contain anything that looks like I would expect (there are a couple of cookies that I'm setting in the app, and none of them are appearing).  All google turns up is a bunch of people suggesting that it's a bad idea to access cookies in integration tests.  I'm running Rails 5.1.2 if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Rails earlier versions change the behavior, the Rails tutorial seems to be deprecated due to an older version Rails.

To pass tests you can forget helper like:

```
class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  ...

  test "remember if checked in login" do
    post login_path, params: { session: { email: @user.email, password: "password", remember_me: '1'}}
    assert_not_empty cookies[:remember_token]
  end

  test "no remember if not checked in login" do
    post login_path, params: { session: { email: @user.email, password: "password", remember_me: '1'}}
    post login_path, params: { session: { email: @user.email, password: "password", remember_me: '0'}}
    assert_empty cookies[:remember_token]
  end

  ...

end
```